# How to get current week number and year in Java using GregorianCalendar?

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

I would like to get current week number and year. I tried following snippet

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.GERMANY);
Date today = new Date();
cal.setTime(today);

int current_week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
```

For today's date(31st Dec 2019) Week number is **01 2020**
but above code gives **01 2019**.

How should I get Week number as **01 2020**?

Here 01 is week number and 2020 is year

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: What is your definition of week numbers?

Comment: Week number means week in the year with year.For example 30th dec 2019 will show as 1 2020. Here 1 is week number and 2020 is year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two points:

1. Week numbering differs by locale. So you are doing the right thing by making it explicit in your code for which locale you want the week number (while I think that most locales in the world agree that December 31, 2019 is in week 1 of 2020, the same agreement does not extend to all dates).
2. The classes `Date`, `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` are poorly designed and long outdated. Don’t use any of those. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

In code:

```
    Locale userLocale = Locale.GERMANY;
    WeekFields weekNumbering = WeekFields.of(userLocale);

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.DECEMBER, 31);
    int currentWeek = date.get(weekNumbering.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
    int year = date.get(weekNumbering.weekBasedYear());

    System.out.format(userLocale, "Week number: %02d %04d%n", currentWeek, year);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> Week number: 01 2020

If you didn’t need the numbers, but the week number as a string, it’s more convenient to use a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter weekFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ww YYYY", userLocale);
    String formattedWeek = date.format(weekFormatter);
    System.out.println("Week number: " + formattedWeek);
```

Output is the same as before.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `calendar.getWeekYear()`

```
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.GERMANY);
        Date today = new Date();
        cal.setTime(today);

        int current_week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        System.out.println("Week: "+current_week);
        System.out.println("Year: "+year);


        System.out.println("Week Year: "+cal.getWeekYear());
```